# Using RestTemplate to call controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller, spring-boot

So I've got this Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="resetemail")
    public ResponseEntity sendPasswordResetEmail (@RequestParam("name")     final String name,
                                       @RequestParam("password") final String password,
                                       @RequestParam("email")    final String email)
    {
        final boolean success = notificationService.sendPasswordResetEmail(name, password, email);
        return success ?
                new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

And I want to call this method from a different controller. I know that restTemplate can be used to do this, but I've tried some options and none of them work. Any hint please?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to call controller method from another controller, any specific use case? 
What I can see from your code, you are trying to send password reset mail to a customer / entity. So instead of calling another controllers method, why don't you just access `notificationService` and call `sendPasswordResetEmail` method. You wanting to call another controller method suggest that you have all the data required to send password reset email.

To summarize, call service method instead of calling another controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, that's the most natural way, but I can't do that as long as long as they're in different modules/micro-services. RestTemplate is my only way.